# Camel - Multicast then performing one route one time only

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I'm trying to call some routes using multicast after multicast performing all the routes I want one route to be executed.
Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
<import resource="classpath:spring/beans.xml" />

    <bean id="properties"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location"
        value="file:///C:\ROI\Generic\Resources\Camel\Constants.properties" />
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:start.queue" />
        <doTry>
            <to uri="stream:out" />
            <process ref="jsonProcessor" />
            <to
                uri="bean:validateInputIdentifiers?method=validation(${property.Source}, ${in.header.Destination})" />
            <to uri="direct:contextRoute" />
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <log message="{{ERROR_MESSAGE}}" />
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:contextRoute" />
        <doTry>
            <to
                uri="bean:contextData?method=populateContainerInfo(${property.Source}, ${property.Destination})" />
            <to uri="bean:contextManager?method=setContextData" />
            <to uri="bean:contextManager?method=getContextData" />
            <process ref="contextProcessor" />
            <multicast>
                <to
                    uri="seda:moveRestrictionRoute" />
                <to
                    uri="seda:mixingRuleValidationRoute" />
            </multicast>
    <to uri="direct:executeMoveInventoryRoute" />

            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <log message="{{ERROR_MESSAGE}}" />
            </doCatch>

        </doTry>
    </route>

 <route>
        <from uri="seda:moveRestrictionRoute" />
        <doTry>
            <to
                uri="bean:moveRestrictionValidation?method=validation(${property.SourceMap}, ${property.DestinationMap})" />
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <log message="{{ERROR_MESSAGE}}" />
            </doCatch>

        </doTry>
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="seda:mixingRuleValidationRoute" />
        <doTry>
            <to
                uri="bean:mixingRuleValidation?method=validation(${property.SourceMap}, ${property.DestinationMap})" />
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <log message="{{ERROR_MESSAGE}}" />
            </doCatch>

        </doTry>
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:executeMoveInventoryRoute" />
        <doTry>
            <to
                uri="bean:executeMoveInventory?method=move(${property.SourceMap}, ${property.DestinationMap}, ${property.Quantity}, ${property.Item})" />
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <log message="{{ERROR_MESSAGE}}" />
            </doCatch>

        </doTry>
    </route>  

</camelContext>
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false" />
</bean>
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Here the problem I'm facing is that after execution of moveRestrictionRoute it is calling  executeMoveInventory route and also after execution of mixingRuleVlidationRoute it is again calling executeMoveInventoryRoute.

What I want is that moveRestrictionRoute  and mixingRuleVlidationRoute  executes in multicast and after execution of both moveRestrictionRoute  and mixingRuleVlidationRoute then only executeMoveInventory calls (i.e only one time).

Comment: If you simply leave out the multicast, would it not work like you want it? I.e. call `moveRestrictionRoute`, then `mixingRuleValidationRoute`, then `executeMoveInventoryRoute` for every exchange? The only difference would be that `mixingRuleValidationRoute` would receive the exchange as it is returned by `moveRestrictionRoute`.

Comment: May be you should use multicast parallel processing with direct endpoints instead of seda .

Comment: @Ralf I want moveRestrictionRoute and mixingRuleValidationRoute to execute parallely. After these two executed successfully then executeMoveInventory should get called and that too only once.

Comment: @Sagar That won't make a difference for what I want to achieve.

Comment: To me the documentation about the default multi-cast aggregation strategy suggests that it is supposed to work the way you intend: "_By default Camel will use the last reply as the outgoing message._". I would implement my own aggregation strategy and try and see if you can get it to work like this. Also, if you want the processing to be parallel, you have to tell the multi-cast component to do so by setting `parallelProcessing="true"`.

Comment: @Ralf Can you share the basic aggregator I can use in here with my example code?

Comment: You can set breakpoints in `org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor` to check what aggregation strategy implementation is used in your case.